# Water supply for refrigerator in garage

Tags: refrigerator

I have an older refrigerator that has a working ice maker that I want to put in my garage to have a second supply of ice when needed.  The only water supply in the garage is an outdoor spigot.  I wondered if I could potentially tap into this for a water supply for the refrigerator?  Is it technically possible?  If so, is it a bad idea for unforeseen reasons?  The garage has a garage door that is closed most of the time, so it is not directly exposed to the elements.

Comment: How long does that spigot go between uses - think of the kitchen tap water does not stay in it for more than a few hours, but that spigot? odd car washes, summer watering...

Comment: Are you in a freezing climate? Is the outdoor spigot frost free?

Comment: It is not actually being used right now, and I do not know if it's frost free, but I think it is.  I live in Cincinnati, so temps get below freezing during the winter regularly.  We currently keep soda & drinks in the garage on a shelf.  During the winter time they will get nice & cold & ready to drink, but not frozen.  I guess my biggest concern was water pressure & how I'd actually hook it up.

Comment: The spigot is not actually being used, I mean.